# Pushing indices into inter-column spacing in tables automatically

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a table that is very slightly to wide for the page. It contains table notes `\tnote{}` and these are what made my table too wide. Now I recall from the documentation of one of several packages that go together to make complicated tables work that one of the authors put in a switch to enable indices to be pushed into the inter-column spacing. I'm aware that I can manually put in `!{}` and `@{}` type specifiers to try and sort things out but I thought that there was something automatic that did it. I am using these packages that relate to tables: `siunitx, dcolumn, array, threeparttable, multirow, longtable, booktabs` and have tried and failed to find the option in the documentation.

Can any one remember what the command is?, probably something that goes in the table preamble.

Thanks.

Edit: here is an example (the doc preamble is a bit of a mouthful, I'm afraid i just copied and pasted this.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[sort]{cleveref}
\usepackage[online]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[output-complex-root=\text{\ensuremath{i}}  % Says that I want italic maths i to signify imaginary components.
            ,load-configurations=abbreviations         % Enables many abbreviations like \eV, however this has separate scope to doc wide macros.
            ,detect-weight                             % Detect the weighting (bold) of surrounding text.
            ,range-units=single                        % Can specify a range like 1 to 2eV or 1eV to 2eV. \SIrange{1}{2}{\eV}
            ,list-units=single                         % Same as range-units only for list. \SIlist{1;2;3;4}{\eV}
            ,table-alignment=center                    % Sets -number- -text- -unit- alignment to center unless superceeded in \sisetup{}. 
                                                       % If not set, then numbers centered on radix. if set, must specify format for correct placement
            ,group-digits=false                        % separates digits into blocks of three (can change other settings to make it comma separated.
            ]{siunitx} % for proper typesetting of units, still under development as best as i can tell... I'm scared \si{} \SI{}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
   \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
           \toprule
           things              & more things              & bumbily boo              & Numbers \\
           \midrule
           1.23412435\tnote{a} & 123543124513452\tnote{b} & dogCatWolfSheep\tnote{c} & -2.1214153124\tnote{d} \\
           \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
   \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) showing a reduced version of your actual table?

Answer (score 2):

In generating the example above I realized that the `\tnote` command was part of the three part table package. The command I wanted is `\TPTrlap` to be placed in the optional argument of the `threeparttable` environment. From the manual: `A command with one argument, to make notes go out of the column, into the column separation (for right-aligning)`.

Further to this answer. I find that `threeparttable` pushes the `\tnote{}` to the intercolumn spacing by default and will do this in the case of a siunitx S column as well. One simply needs to make no mention of the size of the table note in the `table-align-text-post={a}` argument which adds space for non numerical data. It will allow the notes to creep into the intercolumn spacing without producing hbox overful errors.